# List muda de cor na posição errada

Tags: android, listview

[image: Estou com o problema desta imagem:]Fiz um método para quando eu clicar em um item do listView ele mudar de cor.

O problema é que também muda de cor todos os itens que tem um intervalo de 12 itens do item que eu cliquei. 
Por exemplo: 
tenho um listView com números de 1 à 30, se eu clicar no número 1 ele vai ficar verde, porém o 13 também 25 também vai. 
Vi que este é um problema do listView mas alguém já teve algum problema parecido e sabe como resolver?

Código que estou usando:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    String stringNomeProduto = adapter.getItem(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Formulario.class);
    i.putExtra("stringNomePais", stringNomePais);
    i.putExtra("stringIdContinente", getIdContinente);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);

    //muda de cor o produto que já foi preenchido

    System.out.println("resultado 2: " + resultado);
    if (adapter.getItem(position).equals(resultado)) {
        View v = adapter.getView(position, view, parent);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }
    adapter.getItem(position);

}
```

Comment: Onde está a ser feita a mudança de cor? Poste esse código.

Comment: meu código é o mais simples possível, acho que não vai ajudar em nada, postei uma imagem mostrando como o listView trabalha, é este problema que estou tendo.

Answer (score 1):

A imagem explica perfeitamente porque isso está a acontecer.

Suponha que o item 1 é aquele em que você muda a cor, como ele é reaproveitado, ao gerar o item 8, ele também aparece com a cor alterada.

Você tem de garantir que ele tenha a cor de "não clicado" antes de poder ser reaproveitado.

O espaço entre linhas em que isso acontece depende do número de linhas que é possível serem apresentadas ao mesmo tempo.
No caso do exemplo da imagem são sete, no seu caso são 12.

Quando uma linha deixa de ser visível, a sua *View* pode ser reaproveitada para ser usada em outra linha.

No seu *adpater*, no método `getView()`, deve colocar a cor respectiva ao caso da linha ter sido ou não clicada.

Comment: é exatamente isso Ramaral, mas nisso que estou apanhando, você sabe como posso garantir que ele tenha a cor de "não clicado"? agradeço desde já.

Comment: Sem ver o seu código não.

Comment: postei o código.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: obrigado, mas já havia tentado isto, não funciona.

Comment: Isso terá de ser feito no *adapter* no método `getView()`